# OpenCPU local installation and use

Tags: opencpu

I have installed R 3.0.3 & OpenCPU package in it.
When I use the library(opencpu) its giving me the url.
When I enter the URL I am getting the Screen of HTTP request options,Method, End Point, parameter file & AJAX Request

I need to post a custom R function on the opencpu to access/test it on my local machine.
Can any one plz help me out.?

Thanks & Regards
Neel

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your function in a package and install the package on your machine.